# Windows Directory property screen:

Tags: windows, properties, screen

In excel VBA I like to read-out the Windows Properties Screen of a directory.
I am looking for the number of sub-directories.
I have written a small piece of code to find out how many sub-directories are in a directory, but it consummes much more time than when I open the properties window of a directory.
My questions are:

1. Is it possible in VBA or VB to read-out the number of
   sub-directories?
2. If so, please give the command and variable name?

Comment: It takes a long time in Explorer as well.  But it doesn't hang the UI, Explorer uses a worker thread to get the job done.  Using threads in VBA is an elusive goal, you'd have to write a COM server to get it done.  Falls in the "nothing is impossible" bracket, the close relative of "is it important enough to add this feature".  It isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the direction in which I can look futher!